# In Javascript how does the object get attached to the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So if I build an Highchart object and attach it to the DOM element:

```
Highcharts.chart('dom-element-id', options);
```

Later on I in other scripts it appears like I can grab that Highchart object by using the DOM.

```
var chart = $('#dom-element-id').highcharts();
```

My question is...is this a native JS ability to store JS objects on DOM elements?  Or is there somesort of Highchart mapper?

If so how does it work?

Comment: You'll notice that `$()` does not actually return a DOM element, but a jQuery collection, which contains DOM elements. jQuery collections are JS objects, so they can obviously be extended at will.

Comment: the `highcharts` method is a jQuery plugin, which was defined like `$.fn.highcharts = function( ... ) { ... };`. That function gets the jQuery object upon which it was called as context (`this`).

Comment: Thanks yall.  So theres a mapping somewhere in the plugin that stores the object dom relationship?

Comment: Also is this mapping stored globally? i.e.  am I able to access this from different modules?